# Reducing a Hermitian tridiagonal matrix to real symmetric tridiagonal form

Tags: algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Edit: I have now found the answer myself, and will write it up nicely on this coming weekend.

A complex Hermitian matrix is unitarily similar to a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix, which one computes as a first step towards full diagonalization, for example using a variation of QR-decomposition using Householder reflections.

But in every source I've found describing reduction of Hermitian matrices to tridiagonal form, it's missing the final step to get a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix from the complex Hermitian tridiagonal matrix that results from the complex Householder reflections. Either the issue is entirely ignored, or it's simply stated that it's possible to make this final transformation. One source even gave it as an exercise for the reader, which is extremely frustrating when that was the single piece of information I was looking for. So now I have to ask: how, concretely, can one compute a unitary transform from Hermitian tridiagonal form to real symmetric tridiagonal form?

I am guessing that something similar to Givens rotations should be used, but I had trouble deriving the equations myself. Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am puzzled about this question. When dealing with a dense matrix $H$, the standard preprocessing step is to reduce to upper Hessenberg form $T$ using two-sided orthogonal transformations. You can either use Givens rotations or Householder reflectors. When $H$ is Hermitian, then $T$ becomes triangular. The diagonal of T is real, because $T$ is also Hermitian. The fact that the subdiagonal entries of $T$ are real follows from the nature of the Givens/Householder transformations. Exactly how are your sources doing the reduction to tridiagonal form?

Comment: Hi Carl Christian, while it's true that $H$ becomes tridiagonal, when transforming it using the Householder reflections, it does not become real. Reflections leave a nonzero phase in the subdiagonal. One must either afterwards perform a postprocessing step that unitarily transforms from Hermitian tridiagonal to symmetric tridiagonal, or use another unitary transformation than reflection in order to get the symmetric tridiagonal form directly 

I have since found the solution, which is described here: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/235815.235817
(continued)

Comment: (continued). The solution is to construct an elementary unitary transformation which is *not* a reflection, but closely related to the Householder transformation in form. This can directly transform a Hermitian matrix to real tridiagonal form instead of complex Hermitian tridiagonal form.

Comment: My thanks for this information.

Comment: Are you still planning to write up an answer?

Comment: @Mason I had thought there was no interest, since there was no engagement with the question. I'll be happy to write up the answer.

Comment: @James (+1) I would be very interested in seeing the answer. Is it still possible to write it up?

Comment: @James I'd also be interested in seeing your answer :)